# How to take the suffix in smoothing of Part of speech tagging

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger

I am making a "Part of speech Tagger". I am handling the unknown word with the suffix.

But the main issue is that how would i decide the number of suffix... should it be pre-decided (like Weischedel approach) or I have to take the last few alphabets of the words(like Samuelsson approach).

Which approach would be better......

Comment: Suffix might not be enough... most OOV words are named entity which suffixes don't tell much about their POS. You might want to consider other features such as capitalization of the first letter, presence of digits, etc...

Comment: Btw are you developing a probabilistic POS tagger, or rule-based, or hybrid?

Comment: Is it designed to process English text?

Comment: yes ... this is for English language... I am developing probabilistic tag.....

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling suggests that the Weischedel approach is sufficient for English, which has only rudimentary morphological inflection.  The Samuelsson approach seems to work better (which makes sense intuitively) when it comes to processing inflecting languages.

[A Resource-light Approach to Morpho-syntactic Tagging - Google Books p 9](http://books.google.fi/books?id=3eJYlek56jMC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=samuelsson+suffix&source=bl&ots=pzazWMo4DK&sig=tjyVcMXbkwaGhdcAbXjDQfS90AE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1yD0U_iXOYeo4gTd54CwBA&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAg) quote:

> To handle unknown words [Brants (2000)](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~thorsten/publications/Brants-ANLP00.pdf) uses Samuelsson's (1993) suffix analysis, which seems to work best for inflected languages.

(This is not in a direct comparison to Weischedel's approach, though.)